# vertx clustering: org.vertx.java.core.json.DecodeException: Failed to decode:Unexpected character (Clustering)

Tags: hazelcast, vert.x

Everything is working great is an all in one Vertx app. But when using clustering getting the above exception in the event bus (no flow through errors to handlers) when using Hazelcast clustering. Since some of the data being passed by JSON is LARGE I am assuming that data is getting truncated and causing this. Since then same error happens in HTTP if you don't set Receive/Send buffer size big enough I though that setting them in Hazelcast like:

```
System.setProperty("hazelcast.socket.receive.buffer.size", "128000");
System.setProperty("hazelcast.socket.send.buffer.size", "128000");
```

Would fix things it does not. Error looks like:

```
SEVERE: Unhandled exception
org.vertx.java.core.json.DecodeException: Failed to decode:Unexpected character ('c'    (code 99)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
```

at [Source: java.io.StringReader@4d7f405e; line: 1, column: 18]
    at org.vertx.java.core.json.impl.Json.decodeValue(Json.java:63)

Any ideas?? And yes the Json objects are LARGE (thank you hashed values).

Answer (score 0):

I've used vert.x to build an high performance image resizer distributed in cluster ... the similar limitation I found was on image bigger than 10mb that I sent through the event bus in byte format (honestly don't remember if those were truncated or message did not reach destination) -- however since I didn't want such huge messages to travel across the cluster I've put the data in a SharedMap and then sent a jsonmessage containing only the key of the element within the map. If it's for a computation you can use same behaviour, if instead you need to "share" these json accross the cluster you could evaluate the compression/decompression -- afaik vert.x still doesn't support shared data among different jvm instance.

HTH,
Carlo

Comment: Thank you appreciate this. Turns out the problem was trying to send a custom implementation of a Number through set number. Worked in inproc mode as it is a memcopy and then died in cluster mode as it did not know how to deserialize it!